# Sony Stamina Mode - Get Stamina mode status (on/off) from code

Tags: android, sony, sony-xperia

My app is having great trouble in Stamina Mode. I just want to check from code either stamina mode is on or off because i want to turn my app background processing off when stamina mode is on.

Some other solution is also welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically detect SONY - Stamina device energy profile is ON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845479/how-to-programmatically-detect-sony-stamina-device-energy-profile-is-on)